# Laravel file upload (multiple)

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I have a small app where I can can upload multiple files one by one (not at once) but for some reason, each time I upload a file, the other one just disappears.

As shown in the screenshots below :

[image]

[image]

If I `dd($request->all());, only one file is listed.

Here's my controller :

```
 public function profileUpdate(Request $request, User $user)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'firstname' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'address' => 'nullable|string',
        'city' => 'nullable|string',
        'postal' => 'nullable|string',
        'phone' => 'nullable|string',
        'cni' => 'nullable|file',
        'vitale' => 'nullable|file',
    ]);


    $user = Auth::user();

    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->firstname = $request->firstname;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->address = $request->address;
    $user->city = $request->city;
    $user->postal = $request->postal;
    $user->phone = $request->phone;
    $user->vitale = $request->vitale;
    $user->cni = $request->cni;

    $image = $request->file('image');


    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $fileName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileExtension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $image->move('users-photos', $fileName);
        $user->image = 'users-photos/' . $fileName;

    }
    // unlink('users-photos/' . $fileName);

    $cni = $request->file('cni');

    if ($request->hasFile('cni')) {
        $fileName = $cni->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileExtension = $cni->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $cni->move('users-cni', $fileName);
        $user->cni = 'users-cni/' . $fileName;
    }

    $vitale = $request->file('vitale');

    if ($request->hasFile('vitale')) {
        $fileName = $vitale->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileExtension = $vitale->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $vitale->move('users-vitales', $fileName);
        $user->vitale = 'users-vitales/' . $fileName;
    }


    if ($request['password'] != "") {
        if (!(Hash::check($request['password'], Auth::user()->password))) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', "Le mot de passe entré n'est pas valide ");
        }

        if (strcmp($request['password'], $request['new_password']) == 0) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', "Le nouveau mot de passe doit être différent de l'ancien");
        }

        $validation = $request->validate([
            'password' => 'required',
            'new_password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed'
        ]);

        $user->password = Hash::make($request['new_password']);

    }

    $user->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with('success','Profil mis à jour');
}
```

}

The form in my blade file (reduced on purpose) :

```
<form action="{{ route('teacher.teacher.profileUpdate', $user) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
<div class="tab-pane" id="docs" role="tabpanel">
    <h4 class="font-w400 mb-5 mt-3">Documents</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="block">
                <div class="block-header">
                    <h3 class="block-title">CNI</h3>
                    <div class="block-options">
                        <a href="{{ asset(Auth::user()->cni) }}" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
                            download="nom_de_fichier"> <i class="fas fa-download"></i> Télécharger</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="block-content">
                    <img class="" src="{{ asset(Auth::user()->cni) }}" alt="" width="100%">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="d-block" for="cni">File Input</label>
                        <input type="file" id="cni" name="cni">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="block">
                <div class="block-header">
                    <h3 class="block-title">Carte Vitale</h3>
                    <div class="block-options">
                        <a href="{{ asset(Auth::user()->vitale) }}" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
                            download="nom_de_fichier">
                            <i class="fas fa-download"></i> Télécharger
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="block-content">
                    <img class="" src="{{ asset(Auth::user()->vitale) }}" alt="" width="100%">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="d-block" for="vitale">File Input</label>
                        <input type="file" id="vitale" name="vitale">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group text-right">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-alt-danger">
        <i class="fas fa-save mr-1"></i> Mettre à jour
    </button>
</div>
```

Thank you all!

Peace

Comment: Seems like you have multiple name attribute. Then change `name="cni"` to `name="cni[]"` also for vitale

Comment: Thank you @sta I now get this errore `Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on array ` Thanks for your help !

Comment: Which `one just file disappears` in your request?

Comment: If I upload 1 (it doesn't matter which) the other one disappears. If you look at the screenshots you will see that I uploaded Vitale first and when I uploaded Cni, Vitale was gone. I am missing something here ,,, Very strange!